# Filtering Parcels by Valid Pixel Percentage for Statistics Calculation in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, image-processing, filtering, google-earth-engine

I'm working on a Google Earth Engine project where I need to calculate statistics (mean, standard deviation) of vegetation indices for different parcels. However, some images have significant cloud cover, affecting the statistics' accuracy.

My goal is to filter out parcels with less than 50% valid pixels to ensure statistics are calculated using reliable information.

- I'm using the Sentinel-2 image collection ("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED").
- I've implemented functions for calculating vegetation index statistics.
- I need help integrating the valid pixel percentage filtering into the processing workflow.

```
var parcelas = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/resag-1/assets/PAR_22_Cebada')


var convencional = ee.FeatureCollection(parcelas)
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('Manejo','convencional'));

var conservacion = ee.FeatureCollection(parcelas)
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('Manejo','conservacion'));
 
    
var addindices = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('NDVI');
  var CRC1 = image.normalizedDifference(['B11','B2']).rename('CRC1');
  var NDSVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B11','B4']).rename('NDSVI');  /// normalized Diff Moisture Index
  var NDI7 = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B12']).rename('NDI7'); 
  var NDI5 = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B11']).rename('NDI5');
  var NDRI = image.normalizedDifference(['B12','B3']).rename('NDRI'); 
  var DFI = image.expression(                                               
      '100*(1-B12/B11)*(B4/B8A)', {         
      'B11': image.select('B11'),
      'B12': image.select('B12'),
      'B4' : image.select('B4'),
      'B8A': image.select('B8A')
    }).rename('DFI'); 
  var NDI3 = image.normalizedDifference(['B4','B12']).rename('NDI3'); 
  var NDI4 = image.normalizedDifference(['B8A','B12']).rename('NDI4'); 
  var RATIO = image.expression(                                               /// Triangle vegetation index
      'B12/B11'/*10000*/, {         
      'B11': image.select('B11'),
      'B12': image.select('B12')
    }).rename('RATIO');
  var MCRC = image.normalizedDifference(['B11','B3']).rename('MCRC'); 
  var SRNDI = image.normalizedDifference(['B12','B4']).rename('SRNDI'); 
  var NDTI = image.normalizedDifference(['B11','B12']).rename('NDTI'); /// normalized Diff Red Edge Index
  var STI = image.expression(                                               /// Triangle vegetation index
      'B11/B12',{         // DIVIDIDO PARA 10000 POR LA REFLECTANCIA ADICIONAL 10 PARA RANGO
      'B11': image.select('B11'),
      'B12': image.select('B12')
    }).rename('STI');
  return image.addBands([ndvi,CRC1,NDSVI,NDI7,NDI5,MCRC,SRNDI,NDTI,STI,RATIO,DFI,NDI3,NDI4,NDRI]);
};



// Funcion mask clouds
function maskclouds_scl(imagen) {
  var scl = imagen.select('SCL');
  // Seleccionar las clases de vegetacion, suelo, agua y nieve
  var veg = 4;
  var soil = 5;
  var water = 6;
  var snow = 11;
  // Mascara
  var mask = scl.eq(veg).or(scl.eq(soil)).or(scl.eq(water)).or(scl.eq(snow));
  var properties = imagen.propertyNames();
  var imagen_mask = ee.Image(imagen.updateMask(mask).copyProperties(imagen,properties));
  return imagen_mask;
}


//sentinel-2 LA2
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED");

var dataset = S2.filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31'))
                // filtro inicialmente por nubosidad
                  //.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10))
                  .filterBounds(parcelas)
                  .map(maskclouds_scl)
                  .map(addindices)
                  .select('B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12',
                          'NDVI','CRC1','NDSVI','NDI7','NDTI','STI','NIRv','MCRC','SRNDI','NDI5','RATIO','DFI','NDI3','NDI4','NDRI');
print(dataset)                  

//STATISTICS

var stats = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return convencional.map(function(f){
    var mean = image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),geometry: f.geometry(),scale: 20});
    var std = image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),geometry: f.geometry(),scale: 20});
    return f.set({
      'date': image.date().format(),
      // MEDIA
      'NDVI_mean': mean.get('NDVI'),'CRC1_mean': mean.get('CRC1'),
      'NDSVI_mean': mean.get('NDSVI'),'NDI7_mean': mean.get('NDI7'),
      'NDTI_mean': mean.get('NDTI'),'STI_mean': mean.get('STI'),
      'MCRC_mean': mean.get('MCRC'),
      'SRNDI_mean': mean.get('SRNDI'),'NDI5_mean': mean.get('NDI5'),
      'RATIO_mean': mean.get('RATIO'),'DFI_mean': mean.get('DFI'),
      'NDI3_mean': mean.get('NDI3'),'NDI4_mean': mean.get('NDI4'),
      'NDRI_mean': mean.get('NDRI'),
      // DESVIACION ESTANDAR
      'NDVI_std': std.get('NDVI'),'CRC1_std': std.get('CRC1'),
      'NDSVI_std': std.get('NDSVI'),'NDI7_std': std.get('NDI7'),
      'NDTI_std': std.get('NDTI'),'STI_std': std.get('STI'),
      'MCRC_std': std.get('MCRC'),
      'SRNDI_std': std.get('SRNDI'),'NDI5_std': std.get('NDI5'),
      'RATIO_std': std.get('RATIO'),'DFI_std': std.get('DFI'),
      'NDI3_std': std.get('NDI3'),'NDI4_std': std.get('NDI4'),
      'NDRI_std': std.get('NDRI')
    });
  });
})
.flatten()
// MEDIA
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDVI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('CRC1_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDSVI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI7_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDTI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('STI_mean', null)).
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('MCRC_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('SRNDI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI5_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('RATIO_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('DFI_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI3_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI4_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDRI_mean', null))
// DESVIACION ESTANDAR
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDVI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('CRC1_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDSVI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI7_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDTI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('STI_std', null)).
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('MCRC_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('SRNDI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI5_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('RATIO_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('DFI_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI3_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI4_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDRI_std', null));
// Export
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: stats,
  description: 'index_S2_cons',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  folder: ''
}); 

//Estadisticas conservacion
var stats = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return conservacion.map(function(f){
    var mean = image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),geometry: f.geometry(),scale: 20});
    var std = image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),geometry: f.geometry(),scale: 20});
    return f.set({
      'date': image.date().format(),
      'NDVI_mean': mean.get('NDVI'),'CRC1_mean': mean.get('CRC1'),
      'NDSVI_mean': mean.get('NDSVI'),'NDI7_mean': mean.get('NDI7'),
      'NDTI_mean': mean.get('NDTI'),'STI_mean': mean.get('STI'),
      'MCRC_mean': mean.get('MCRC'),
      'SRNDI_mean': mean.get('SRNDI'),'NDI5_mean': mean.get('NDI5'),
      'RATIO_mean': mean.get('RATIO'),'DFI_mean': mean.get('DFI'),
      'NDI3_mean': mean.get('NDI3'),'NDI4_mean': mean.get('NDI4'),
      'NDRI_mean': mean.get('NDRI'),
      // DESVIACION ESTANDAR
      'NDVI_std': std.get('NDVI'),'CRC1_std': std.get('CRC1'),
      'NDSVI_std': std.get('NDSVI'),'NDI7_std': std.get('NDI7'),
      'NDTI_std': std.get('NDTI'),'STI_std': std.get('STI'),
      'MCRC_std': std.get('MCRC'),
      'SRNDI_std': std.get('SRNDI'),'NDI5_std': std.get('NDI5'),
      'RATIO_std': std.get('RATIO'),'DFI_std':  std.get('DFI'),
      'NDI3_std':  std.get('NDI3'),'NDI4_std':  std.get('NDI4'),
      'NDRI_std':  std.get('NDRI')
    });
  });
})
.flatten()
// MEDIA
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDVI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('CRC1_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDSVI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI7_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDTI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('STI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('MCRC_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('SRNDI_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI5_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('RATIO_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('DFI_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI3_mean', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI4_mean', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDRI_mean', null))
// DESVIACION ESTANDAR
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDVI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('CRC1_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDSVI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI7_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDTI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('STI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('MCRC_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('SRNDI_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI5_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('RATIO_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('DFI_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI3_std', null))
.filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDI4_std', null)).filter(ee.Filter.neq('NDRI_std', null));




// Export
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: stats,
  description: 'index_S2_con',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  folder: ''
});
```